# Sci fi novel from 1970s where father and son swap bodies

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

I'm trying to recall the name of a sci fi novel where a wimpy, sickly son swaps bodies with his tough military father. I think it had a picture of some kind of futuristic gun on the cover.

Comment: Was the body swapping a major theme of the novel? Where was the book set (planet, space, future, etc), why was the boy sickly? What branch of the military was the father in? What events led up to them swapping and what were the consequences?

Answer (score 3):

Was it part of [this series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help!_I'm_Trapped...) of young adult novels?

From the wiki link above:

> Help! I'm Trapped... is a series of 17 books written by Todd Strasser,
>   published by Scholastic Press. With worldwide sales of over 10 million
>   copies, the plots mainly center around a group of children and a
>   machine that has the power to switch bodies.
>
> The characters include Jake Sherman, who is usually the one "trapped
>   in" someone else's body, his sister Jessica, his two friends Andy and
>   Josh, and their science teacher who made the machine. Recurring
>   characters include Jake's parents and dog and the principal.
>
> The first of the series, Help! I'm Trapped in my Teacher's Body, was
>   published in 1993.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this. How/why does your suggestion meet the OP's requirements?

Comment: It would greatly help this post if you included a small summary of the book (quoted and cited appropriately) and a description of how it fits the question.